# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in weka.classifiers.Classifier.classifyInstance

Tags: java, weka, indexoutofboundsexception

I have written this method. I want to write a Bayesian Network, but I get an exception on the `classifyInstance()` method.

Here is my code:

```
public static double bayesNet1(Dataset data, Dataset testingSet) throws Exception {

        Instances insts = convertTxtToARFF(data);
        K2 learner = new K2();
        MultiNomialBMAEstimator estimator = new MultiNomialBMAEstimator();
        estimator.setUseK2Prior(true);

        EditableBayesNet bn = new EditableBayesNet(insts);
        bn.initStructure();
        learner.buildStructure(bn, insts);
        estimator.estimateCPTs(bn);

        double error = 0;

        Instances instsTest = convertTxtToARFF(testingSet);

        for(int i=0; i<instsTest.numInstances()-1; i++) {

        weka.core.Instance inst = instsTest.instance(i);

        double  predictedValue = bn.classifyInstance(inst);

        if(inst.value(inst.classIndex())!= predictedValue)

            error++;

        }

        return error/instsTest.numInstances();
    }
```

And here is the exception:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4   at
>   weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.DiscreteEstimatorBayes.getProbability(DiscreteEstimatorBayes.java:106)
>     at
>   weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator.distributionForInstance(SimpleEstimator.java:183)
>     at
>   weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet.distributionForInstance(BayesNet.java:386)
>     at weka.classifiers.Classifier.classifyInstance(Classifier.java:84)
>     at
>   ensembleClassifiersV2.EnsembleClassifierV2.bayesNet1(EnsembleClassifierV2.java:1090)
>     at
>   ensembleClassifiersV2.EnsembleClassifierV2.performing(EnsembleClassifierV2.java:800)
>     at
>   ensembleClassifiersV2.EnsembleClassifierV2.main(EnsembleClassifierV2.java:1267)

Can anyone help me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My fault is I had not set the class for the test data. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this error commonly occurs in the `distributionForInstance()` method for many of the different classifiers when you are dealing with nominal attributes.

If this is the case, it could be that the test data has a nominal attribute with an attribute value that the train data lacks.

In this case, it really depends upon what the best decision is for what you are doing.  Perhaps checking the data itself for consistency is the first step and then you go from there.